# Find the minimum range

Tags: algorithms, integers

Given a list of numbers as `L`, how do you find the minimum value `m` such that `L` can be made into a strictly ascending list by adding or subtracting values from `[0,m]` from each element of `L` except the last? (Strictly ascending means the new list can't have any duplicates.)

Example #1:

```
for L = [5, 4, 3, 2, 8] the minimum value for `m` is 3. 
5 - 3 = 2 # subtract by 3
4 - 1 = 3 # subtract by 1
3 + 1 = 4 # add by 1
2 + 3 = 5 # add by 3
8 untouched # nothing

result = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

Example #2:

```
for L = [5, 4, 3, 0, 8], minimum value for `m` is 4
```

**NOTE**: I'm not looking for a complete solution just give me few thoughts and clue.

Comment: Try first solving the problem for very short $L$, say of sizes $2,3,4$. Then come up with a formula. Then come up with an efficient algorithm for computing it.

Comment: Maybe try dynamic programming. Do you have more examples for checking?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, @hengnix. Thanks. I know it must be solved by DP and some kind of backtracking but I'm unable to find a good way to solve it even for a short list. Let's say, I pick the `min` of the list (here 2) and then iterate over the list and try to find the minimum value `m` that either `item + m` or `item - m` is still greater than `min` . Now, next item and updated `min` and so on. But that doesn't take me any where.

Comment: @hengxin, I'll try to find some more examples. That's gonna help. There are few solutions that I'm not sure if correct or not. But I don't understand their logic.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/2bethere/680aebe7a9da8744b838), [here](http://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=80590&page=1&authorid=1954) and [here](http://hehejun.blogspot.com/2015/01/algorithmhill.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I try to prove that the greedy algorithm ($\mathcal{A}$) given by [@norbertpy](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41507/4911) (and [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076632/1833118)) is correct. *Please check it.*

---

**Problem Definition:**

The algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ of @norbertpy is for a variant of the original problem:

> To find the minimum positive number $2m$ such that for each item in the array, **adding** a number from $[0, 2m]$ can lead to a strictly ascending array?

The solutions to these two problems can be reduced to each other (by $\pm m$).
Note that I have ignored the "except the last" part.

---

**A lemma for the property of the algorithm $\mathcal{A}$:**

Let $L'[n]$ be the last element of the resulting strictly ascending list of any feasible solution to $L[1 \ldots n]$. We first claim that:

> **Lemma:** $\mathcal{A}$ gives the *smallest* value of $L'[n]$ among all the feasible solutions to $L[1 \ldots n]$.

This lemma can be proved by mathematical induction on the length $n$ of $L$.

---

**Now we prove that $\mathcal{A}$ always gives the optimal solution.**

**Base case:** $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ are trivial.

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Suppose that for any $L[1 \cdots n-1]$ of length $n-1$, the algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ gives us the optimal solution $m$.

**Inductive Step:** Consider the $n$-th iteration of the greedy algorithm $\mathcal{A}$: it compare `a = head + 1 - L[n]` with $m$, and take $M = \max(m,a)$ as the feasible solution to $L[1 \cdots n]$.

We aim to prove that

> $M$ is the optimal solution to $L[1 \cdots n]$.

Suppose, by contradiction, that there is another feasible solution to $L[1 \cdots n]$, denoted by $M' < M$.

First, $m < M'$: otherwise, $M'$ is a *smaller* feasible solution to $L[1 \cdots n-1]$, which contradicts the assumption.

Thus we have $m < M' < M$. Because $M = \max(m,a)$, we obtain $m < M' < M = a$.

By the lemma above, $L'[n-1]$ in the solution corresponding to $M'$ is not less than that in the solution corresponding to $m$. However, $L'[n]$ (for $M'$) is less than that for $M$ (because $M' < a$). According to the way how $a$ is chosen in $\mathcal{A}$, the resulting array (for $M'$) is not strictly ascending. Thus $M'$ cannot be a solution. Contradication.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076632/4228942), I've written this:

```
import math

a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 8]
b = [5, 4, 3, 0, 8]
c = [5, 4, 110, 0, 8]
d = [5, 4, 3, -16, 8]


def hill(a):
    max_m = 0
    head = a[0]
    for item in a[1:]:
        current_m = math.fabs(head + 1 - item)

        if current_m > max_m:
            max_m = current_m

        # update the head for next iteration
        head = item + current_m

    print math.ceil(max_m / 2)

hill(a) # 3.0
hill(b) # 4.0
hill(c) # 107.0
hill(d) # 12.0
```

The logic is, we set the `max_m` to zero and the `head` to first element of the list. We then start iterating through the `list - first element` and find the minimum value `current_m` such that adding `current_m` to the `item` will be equal to `head + 1`. At each iteration of we find a greater `m`, we just store it in `max_m`.

At the end we divide the `m` by 2 since we just used the addition to find the `m` and not the subtraction.

I hope this helps but I'm still not sure if it's correct for all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I took three test cases `L1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 8]`, `L2 = [5, 4, 3, 0, 8]` and `L3 = [4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 7]` and performed the following steps:

1. Take the mean, x of all numbers except the last.

   ```
   x1 = mean(L1') = 3.5
   x2 = mean(L2') = 3
   x3 = mean(L3') = 3.6
   L' is the list excluding last number.
   ```
2. Perform ceil(x) and duplicate the list L into M

   ```
   x1 = 4, x2 = 3, x3 = 4
   ```
3. Start from the center, M'[middle] do:

   ```
   M[i] = --x if i < middle, else
   M[i] = ++x if i > middle.
   ```

Find the maximum difference, **m**(which is the required answer) between each element of `M[i]` and `L[i]`.

http://ideone.com/SwwXjm